# How to get the UserUnit property from a PdfFile using iTextSharp PdfReader

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a bunch of PDF files- I read these as requested into a byte array and then also pass it to a iTextSharp PdfReader instance.  I want to then grab the dimensions of each page- in pixels.  From what I've read so far it seems by PDF files work in points- a point being a configurable unit stored in some kind of dictionary in an element called UserUnit.

Loading my PDF File into a PdfReader, what do I need to do to get the UserUnit for each page (apparently it can vary from page to page) so I can then get the page dimensions in pixels.

At present I have this code, which grabs the dimensions for each page in "points" -  guess I just need the UerUnit, and can then multiply these dimensions by that to get pixels or something similar.

```
//Create an object to read the PDF
PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file_content);

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
  Rectangle dim = reader.GetPageSize(i);
  int[] xy = new int[] { (int)dim.Width, (int)dim.Height };  // returns page size in "points"
  page_data[objectid + '-' + i] = xy;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow me to quote from my book:

iText in Action - Second Edition, page 9:

> **FAQ** *What is the measurement unit in PDF documents?* Most of the measurements
>   in PDFs are expressed in user space units. ISO-32000-1 (section 8.3.2.3) tells us
>   “the default for the size of the unit in default user space (1/72 inch) is
>   approximately the same as a point (pt), a unit widely used in the printing
>   industry. It is not exactly the same; there is no universal definition of a point.”
>   In short, 1 in. = 25.4 mm = 72 user units (which roughly corresponds to 72 pt).

On the next page, I explain that it’s possible to change the default value of the user unit, and I add an example on how to create a document with pages that have a different user unit.

Now for your question: suppose you have an existing PDF, how do you find which user unit was used? Before we answer this, we need to take a look at ISO-32000-1.

In section 7.7.3.3Page Objects, you'll find the description of UserUnit in Table 30, "Entries in a page object":

> (Optional; PDF 1.6) A positive number that shall give the size of
>   default user space units, in multiples of 1⁄72 inch. The range of
>   supported values shall be implementation-dependent. Default value: 1.0
>   (user space unit is 1⁄72 inch).

This key was introduced in PDF 1.6; you won't find it in older files. It's optional, so you won't always find it in every page dictionary. In my book, I also explain that the maximum value of the UserUnit key is 75,000.

**Now how to retrieve this value with iTextSharp?**

You already have `Rectangle dim = reader.GetPageSize(i);` which returns the MediaBox. This may not be the size of the visual part of the page. If there's a CropBox defined for the page, viewers will show a much smaller size than what you have in `xy` (but you probably knew that already).

What you need now is the page dictionary, so that you can retrieve the value of the UserUnit key:

```
PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(i);
PdfNumber userUnit = pageDict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.USERUNIT);
```

Most of the times userUnit will be `null`, but if it isn't you can use `userUnit.FloatValue`.