# In what unit of measure are expressed the absolute position of a table? Can I express this position in cm?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

this is my first time with iText and I have some doubt about the absolute position of a table.

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

try {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(result));

    document.open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.setTotalWidth(100);

    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("TEST TEST TEST TEST"));

    table.completeRow();
    table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 3, 53, canvas);
    document.close();
}catch (DocumentException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

So I have set the absolute position of my table, by this line:

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 3, 53, canvas);
```

and the table is "shifted" from the bottom left corner of the document of X=3 and Y=53

My doubt is: in which unit of measure is expressed this value? pixel? or what?

Can I express these values in cm (centimeters)? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation, for instance the free ebook [The Best Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). You will find questions such as [How to get the UserUnit property from a PdfFile using iTextSharp PdfReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586315/how-to-get-the-userunit-property-from-a-pdffile-using-itextsharp-pdfreader) with callouts such as this one:

[image]

This explains what the measurement unit is in PDF (and iText).

As for your question how to use cm, you can consult the API documentation where you'll find methods such as [millimetersToPoints](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Utilities.html#millimetersToPoints(float)).

Comment: Tnx, I did not know this free ebook, I have downloaded it and I will consult it. Tnx also for your clarification, I think that now it is clear...I only have to try by myself ;-)