# points to inches itext7

Tags: itext, itext7

This is part of iText5 function where page height and width is first fetched and then compared against the input parameters.

```
Rectangle rectangle = page.getPageSize();
float pageHeight    = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.pointsToInches(rectangle.getHeight());
float pageWidth     = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.pointsToInches(rectangle.getWidth());
```

I read through iText7 API and could not find pointsToInches or similar function. Looks like simple thing, I am not sure did I miss it or its dropped in iText7. Anyone know the function or how to convert from points to inches. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By default there are 72 points per inch. I guess you can now do the math...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but it didn't have an answer other than @mkl's comment on the question.  The default UserUnit is 72 per inch, but that can be changed in the Page Dictionary's /UserUnit entry.

It appears that they did ditch the inchesToPoints method, but a direct implementation is trivial: `float points = inches * 72f;`.  An implementation using the page's UserUnit value is [addressed by Bruno in iText 5 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586315/how-to-get-the-userunit-property-from-a-pdffile-using-itextsharp-pdfreader). Adapting it to iText 7 is trivial since PdfDictionary has similar syntax in both.

```cs
public static float pointsToInches(float inches, PdfPage page)
{
    PdfNumber userUnit = page.GetPdfObject().GetAsNumber(PdfName.UserUnit);
    float userUnitValue = userUnit == null ? 72f : userUnit.FloatValue();
    return inches / userUnitValue;
}
```

Edit: It did say `inches / userUnitValue`, but it should be `inches * userUnitValue`.

Comment: yep, I was too lazy to make that comment am actual answer.

Comment: so if I call this method for 1 inch (i.e. `inchesToPoints(1, page)` ) what should it return? 72 or 1/72 ?

Comment: I see your point... It should be inches * userUnitValue.  It's been fixed.  Thanks!